# Sell same product from different distributors

Tags: sku

What's the best way to do this?

Example I want to sell Ipad-mini's.
I can get them from different distributors, with different SKU's.
I'm updating each distributors stock level and prices into Magento via Magmi.

distributor A->SKU: A0011231 Stock: 15 pces
distributor B->SKU: B0457566 Stock: 17 pces
...

Is there a way to manage this by only one SKU? So that search results via MPN  gives only one result.

Comment: Why don't you just use the SKU from Apple?

Comment: don't you want to use marketplace with same sku for bot products with different distributor names on product view page ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use configurable products for this:
You set up one configurable product I-Pad mini with the Apple SKU and then add the different simple products with an own SKU each, depending on the distributor. With this you can give your customer the chance to select a distributor on adding the product to cart and you have an inventory field for each.